# Sync of iPhone copies all songs every time

Tags: iphone, ios, music

Macbook Pro 16" running the latest version of Catalina,
iPhone XS running iOS 14.1

I sync the phone and computer using a lightning cable, **I don't use iCloud.**

Sync used to take five minutes, now takes over an hour.

I have about 20 GB of music on the Mac, I would like a copy of all of it on the phone.

Two months ago I had all the songs on my phone and when I synced the phone to the computer it took about five minutes, very few songs were updated.

Today when I sync my phone with my computer every single song is copied from the computer back to the phone in spite of the fact that all the songs were already on my phone when I plugged it in. These songs haven't been updated and most haven't been played between syncs. I want to say it started with iOS 14 but I am not certain.

This is new behavior. I haven't changed any settings on the Mac or the iPhone.

This happens every time I sync my phone.

My questions:
What is causing this and how can I stop it?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of the following question on Superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/33641/itunes-syncs-the-same-handful-of-songs-on-every-sync